# Codeigniter retrieve rewritten URL parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-parameters

I'm using **Codeigniter** and my page URL is [here](http://www.website.com/en/hotels).

and I want to send this URL to the controller "**adverts**" and method "**search**" with a category parameter "**cat**" and id "**824**". To do so i use the routes like this:

```
$route['^en/hotels$'] = "adverts/search/cat/824";
```

My problem now is that i dont know how to retrieve the rewritten parameters "**cat**" and id "**824**".
When i use `$this->uri->segment_array()` i have the initial request URL:

```
array (size=2) 
  1 => string 'en' (length=2) 
  2 => string 'hotels' (length=16)
```

Please someone can  explain me how to retrieve my parameters?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should declare a method like:

```
function search($cat,$id){

}
```

CodeIgniter will automatically bind URL parameters to method parameters.

Comment: Thank you @Adeel. Yes you are right, but if i want to have a main function to retrieve dynamic parameters like:
`adverts/search/cat/824`
`adverts/search/cat/824/type/xyz` 
`adverts/search/cat/824/type/xyz/mode/10`
I would have to do a method with each parameter signature?

Comment: Suppose you will have max five params, then use default value for others and check accordingly. like function search($a, $b, $c=null, $d=null)